# Custom Activity runningModal. How to trigger only runnnigModal by clicking, without the runningHover

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, custom-activity

I want to trigger the runningModal by clicking on it without the usual flow of, first the hover appearing and clicking More Details button.

The same it works for Data Extension activity so I think it's feasible to do.

I'm trying it with this json configuration but it's not working as expected:

```
"userInterfaces": {
    "configInspector": {
      "size": "large"
    },
    "runningModal": {
      "url": "runningHover.html"
    }
```

This is the working as expected activity configuration but I can't reproduce it in my own:

```
{  
    "workflowApiVersion":"1.1",
    "metaData":{  
        "icon":"/img/email-icon.svg",
        "iconSmall":"/img/email-icon.svg",
        "category":"message",
        "version":"1.0"
    },
    "key":"jb-email-activity",
    "type":"EMAILV2",
    "lang":{  
        "en-US":{  
            "name":"Send Email",
            "description":"Configurable email activity to send an email.",
            "runningHoverButtonLabel":"View or Update Activity"
        },
        "de":{  
            "name":"E-Mail senden"
        },
        "en":{  
            "name":"Send Email"
        },
        "es":{  
            "name":"Enviar correo electrónico"
        },
        "es-XL":{  
            "name":"Enviar correo electrónico"
        },
        "fr":{  
            "name":"Envoyer un email"
        },
        "fr-CA":{  
            "name":"Envoyer un courriel"
        },
        "it":{  
            "name":"Invia e-mail"
        },
        "ja":{  
            "name":"メール送信"
        },
        "pt":{  
            "name":"Enviar Email"
        }
    },
    "userInterfaces":{  
        "configInspector":{  
            "size":"large"
        },
        "runningModal":{  
            "url":"index.html"
        },
        "runningHover":{  
            "url":"index.html#runningHover"
        }
    },
    "supportsEngagementDecision":true,
    "useSso":true,
    "copySettings":{  
        "allowCopy":true
    }
}
```